# Is there a way to initialize graylog inputs via docker volume?

Tags: mongodb, docker, logging, docker-compose, graylog

I would like to initialize my graylog inputs via some config file before container starts? Is there a way to do this, or i need to do this all by graylog gui?

I tried some of chat GPT answers like using this entrypoint:

```
entrypoint: >
      /usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it elasticsearch:9200 -- 
      /docker-entrypoint.sh --initial-inputs /usr/share/graylog/initial-inputs.json
```

with this .json file:

```
[
  {
    "title": "GELF TCP Input",
    "type": "org.graylog2.inputs.gelf.tcp.GELFTCPInput",
    "global": true,
    "configuration": {
      "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 12201
    }
  }
]
```

but it didn't work. Graylog 4.0